# Reading in multiple words for prolog

Tags: input, prolog

Im running prolog via poplog on unix and was wondering if there was a way to read in multiple words (such as encase it into a string).
For instance, read(X) will only allow X to be 1 term. However, if I encase the user input with "", it will return a list of character codes, is this the correct method as I can not find a way to convert it back to a readable string.

I would also like to be able to see if the multiworded string contains a set value (for instance, if it contains "i have been") and am unsure of how i will be able to do this as well.

Comment: In Prolog strings are lists of integers (character codes), so you're getting the right thing. Are you looking for a way to render this returned string correctly to, say, a user?

Answer (score 5):

`read/1` reads one Prolog item from standard input. If you enter a string enclosed in `"`, it will indeed read that string as one object, which is a list of ASCII or Unicode codepoints:

```
?- read(X).
|: "I have been programming in Prolog" .
X = [73, 32, 104, 97, 118, 101, 32, 98, 101|...].
```

Note the period after the string to signify end-of-term. To convert this into an atom (a "readable string"), use `atom_codes`:

```
?- read(X), atom_codes(C,X).
|: "I have been programming in Prolog" .
C = 'I have been programming in Prolog'.
```

Note single quotes, so this is one atom. But then, an atom is atomic (obviously) and thus not searchable. To search, use strings consistently (no `atom_codes`) and something like:

```
/* brute-force string search */
substring(Sub,Str) :- prefix_of(Sub,Str).
substring(Sub,[_|Str]) :- substring(Sub,Str).

prefix_of(Pre, Str) :- append(Pre, _, Str).
```

Then

```
read(X), substring("Prolog",X)
```

succeeds, so the string was found.

Comment: (But in general, stay clear from standard Prolog I/O, it's horrible. Use IPC or embedding so you can write I/O in a language that properly supports it.)

Comment: I think the trick is to use pure methods in Prolog: Write a DCG that describes what you want, and then use library(pio) to apply that DCG to an actual input stream. The advantage of this is that, in contrast to other languages, you can actually test the DCG also in isolation from actual input, just like any pure predicate.

Comment: @mat: I didn't know about the `pio` library (which seems to be SWI only). It indeed looks a lot cleaner than standard Prolog I/O.

Comment: Yes currently "only" SWI (i.e., arguably the most widely used system) has it, and indeed for me it's one of the main reasons to actually use SWI instead of other systems. This library alone makes it completely worth it, because you need to teach/learn only DCGs and can then transparently use them for I/O too. In comparison, see how hard it is to actually test input/output with other languages!

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the most basic and straightforward answer to your question is that you need to enclose your input in single quotes, i.e.:

`read('Multiple Words In A Single Atom').`

The double quotes, as you said, always convert to ASCII codes.